# vb.net - sqlite - SELECTing multiple values in one connection

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm currently working on a database mining program to pull data from a sqlite db and populate a form. This requires simultaneously pulling a few types of data from a few different tables and already seems a little resource-intensive. Is there a better way to approach this? Should I be using a background worker to run the sql query? I am running multiple SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader instances, is it possible to avoid this?

Code:

```
Public Shared Sub SQLInq()

    'Database Information
    Dim connection As String = "Data Source=" & _Compression.path
    Dim SQLConn As New SQLiteConnection(connection)
    Dim SQLcmd As New SQLiteCommand(SQLConn)
    Dim SQLdr As SQLiteDataReader

    'Connect to Database
    SQLConn.Open()
    SQLcmd.Connection = SQLConn

    'Run query
    SQLcmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM FsFileVersion WHERE FileDescription_LTH = 'filea' LIMIT 1;"
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
    While SQLdr.Read()
        fileaVrsn = (SQLdr.GetString(SQLdr.GetOrdinal("FileVersion_LTH")))
    End While
    SQLdr.Close()

    'Run query
    SQLcmd.CommandText = "Select * FROM FsFileVersion WHERE FileDescription_LTH = 'fileb' LIMIT 1;"
    SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
    While SQLdr.Read()
        filebVrsn = (SQLdr.GetString(SQLdr.GetOrdinal("FileVersion_LTH")))
    End While
    SQLdr.Close()

    'Close connection
    SQLConn.Close()

    'Revert cursor wait to arror
    Application.Current.MainWindow.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is.  If it's locking the UI, then yes, use a BackgroundWorker.

Comment: @LarsTech  Is there a better way to approach this? Should I be using a background worker to run the sql query? I am running multiple SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader instances, is it possible to avoid this? My biggest question I guess would be is it possible to run multiple commands in one execute reader as opposed to multiple executereaders?

Comment: Not sure I understand why having multiple instances bugs you. Can you avoid it?  Sure.  Use the `Using...End Using` format for your Connection, Commands and Readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are really interested in only one record (`LIMIT 1`) and only one column (`FileVersion_LTH`) then you could remove the `ExecuteReader` and use just [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim connection As String = "Data Source=" & _Compression.path
Using SQLConn = New SQLiteConnection(connection)
Using SQLcmd = New SQLiteCommand(SQLConn)
    SQLConn.Open()
    SQLcmd.CommandText = "Select FileVersion_LTH FROM FsFileVersion " & _ 
                         "WHERE FileDescription_LTH = 'filea' LIMIT 1;"
    Dim result = SQLcmd.ExecuteScalar()
    if result IsNot Nothing Then 
        fileaVrsn = result.ToString()
    End if

    ... repeat for 'fileb'
End Using
End Using
```

However I am not sure that this is really a performance improvement. Your code seems to be not so bad after all. Just remember to use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

**EDIT** Another possible improvement is to use again the SQLiteDataReader, but executing just one call to the database

....
   SQLcmd.CommandText = "Select FileVersion_LTH FROM FsFileVersion " & _ 
                        "WHERE FileDescription_LTH = 'filea' OR " & _
                               "FileDescription_LTH = 'fileb' " & _
                        "ORDER BY FileDescription_LTH"
   Using SQLiteDataReader reader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
       if reader.Read() Then
           fileaVrsn = reader(0).ToString()
           if reader.Read() Then
              filebVrsn = reader(0).ToString()
           End If
       End If
   End Using
   ...

This second approach could be an improvement but it is feasible only if the LIMIT 1 is not really required

Comment: Good information and definitely something to pursue. The Result is giving me the information from the first column instead of from the column I've specified in the current code as FileVersion_LTH though. *EDIT* Nevermind, noticed the change you made to the query string. Thanks!

Comment: Another possible improvement is to use again the SQLiteDataReader, but executing only one call to the database. I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I dont know sqlite but SQL Server and Oracle allow you to get multiple datatables at once by puting ";" between your SELECT statements. IE, "SELECT * FROM X;SELECT * FROM Y". If you use a dataadapter to fill in a dataset, it will create 2 tables in there. (SQL Server also allows VBCRLF or Environment.NewLine) Maybe you can do some testing or searching to see if sqlite does too.

Second, I have done a lot of testing and if you are returning every record using a datareader, it is **usually** *slightly* faster to just use a dataadapter and fill a datatable. If you are not reading every record in your reader, your should re-evaluate your WHERE clause of the SQL.